# Convert observable d3.js brush and focus example to jsfiddle

Tags: d3.js, observable

I'm having trouble converting this observable example to a jsfiddle.

https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context?collection=@d3/d3-brush

Here's my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/u5g1ychz/1/

Edit: latest fiddle attempt
https://jsfiddle.net/03eagvxk/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Chart</h1>
  <div id="my_chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
}
  
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: #ffab00;
    stroke: #fff;
}
  
  .focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
```

Javascript

```
/* new data */
var x = d3.timeDays(new Date(2010, 06, 01), new Date(2020, 10, 30));
var y = Array.from({length: x.length}, Math.random).map(n => Math.floor(n * 10) + 5);
var data = x.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    "date": v,
    "close": y[i]
  }
});

/* begin observable code */
viewof focus = {
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, focusHeight])
      .style("display", "block");

  const brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[margin.left, 0.5], [width - margin.right, focusHeight - margin.bottom + 0.5]])
      .on("brush", brushed)
      .on("end", brushended);

  const defaultSelection = [x(d3.utcYear.offset(x.domain()[1], -1)), x.range()[1]];

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis, x, focusHeight);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area(x, y.copy().range([focusHeight - margin.bottom, 4])));

  const gb = svg.append("g")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, defaultSelection);

  function brushed({selection}) {
    if (selection) {
      svg.property("value", selection.map(x.invert, x).map(d3.utcDay.round));
      svg.dispatch("input");
    }
  }

  function brushended({selection}) {
    if (!selection) {
      gb.call(brush.move, defaultSelection);
    }
  }

  return svg.node();
}

update = {
  const [minX, maxX] = focus;
  const maxY = d3.max(data, d => minX <= d.date && d.date <= maxX ? d.value : NaN);
  chart.update(x.copy().domain(focus), y.copy().domain([0, maxY]));
}

area = (x, y) => d3.area()
    .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
    
x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    
y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    
xAxis = (g, x, height) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
    
yAxis = (g, y, title) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".title").data([title]).join("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", -margin.left)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(title))
        
margin = ({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40})
height = 440
focusHeight = 100
```

Downloaded observable javascript file

```
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context@326
export default function define(runtime, observer) {
  const main = runtime.module();
  const fileAttachments = new Map([["aapl.csv",new URL("./files/de259092d525c13bd10926eaf7add45b15f2771a8b39bc541a5bba1e0206add4880eb1d876be8df469328a85243b7d813a91feb8cc4966de582dc02e5f8609b7",import.meta.url)]]);
  main.builtin("FileAttachment", runtime.fileAttachments(name => fileAttachments.get(name)));
  main.variable(observer()).define(["md"], function(md){return(
md`# Focus + Context

This [area chart](/@d3/area-chart) uses brushing to specify a focused area. Drag the gray region to pan, or brush to zoom. Compare to a [zoomable chart](/@d3/zoomable-area-chart). Data: [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup)`
)});
  main.variable(observer("chart")).define("chart", ["d3","width","height","DOM","margin","data","xAxis","yAxis","area"], function(d3,width,height,DOM,margin,data,xAxis,yAxis,area)
{
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .style("display", "block");

  const clipId = DOM.uid("clip");

  svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", clipId.id)
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right);

  const gx = svg.append("g");

  const gy = svg.append("g");

  const path = svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", clipId)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue");

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {
    update(focusX, focusY) {
      gx.call(xAxis, focusX, height);
      gy.call(yAxis, focusY, data.y);
      path.attr("d", area(focusX, focusY));
    }
  });
}
);
  main.variable(observer("viewof focus")).define("viewof focus", ["d3","width","focusHeight","margin","x","xAxis","data","area","y"], function(d3,width,focusHeight,margin,x,xAxis,data,area,y)
{
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, focusHeight])
      .style("display", "block");

  const brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[margin.left, 0.5], [width - margin.right, focusHeight - margin.bottom + 0.5]])
      .on("brush", brushed)
      .on("end", brushended);

  const defaultSelection = [x(d3.utcYear.offset(x.domain()[1], -1)), x.range()[1]];

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis, x, focusHeight);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area(x, y.copy().range([focusHeight - margin.bottom, 4])));

  const gb = svg.append("g")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, defaultSelection);

  function brushed({selection}) {
    if (selection) {
      svg.property("value", selection.map(x.invert, x).map(d3.utcDay.round));
      svg.dispatch("input");
    }
  }

  function brushended({selection}) {
    if (!selection) {
      gb.call(brush.move, defaultSelection);
    }
  }

  return svg.node();
}
);
  main.variable(observer("focus")).define("focus", ["Generators", "viewof focus"], (G, _) => G.input(_));
  main.variable(observer("update")).define("update", ["focus","d3","data","chart","x","y"], function(focus,d3,data,chart,x,y)
{
  const [minX, maxX] = focus;
  const maxY = d3.max(data, d => minX <= d.date && d.date <= maxX ? d.value : NaN);
  chart.update(x.copy().domain(focus), y.copy().domain([0, maxY]));
}
);
  main.variable(observer("data")).define("data", ["d3","FileAttachment"], async function(d3,FileAttachment){return(
Object.assign(d3.csvParse(await FileAttachment("aapl.csv").text(), d3.autoType).map(({date, close}) => ({date, value: close})), {y: "↑ Close $"})
)});
  main.variable(observer("area")).define("area", ["d3"], function(d3){return(
(x, y) => d3.area()
    .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
)});
  main.variable(observer("x")).define("x", ["d3","data","margin","width"], function(d3,data,margin,width){return(
d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
)});
  main.variable(observer("y")).define("y", ["d3","data","height","margin"], function(d3,data,height,margin){return(
d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
)});
  main.variable(observer("xAxis")).define("xAxis", ["margin","d3","width"], function(margin,d3,width){return(
(g, x, height) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
)});
  main.variable(observer("yAxis")).define("yAxis", ["margin","d3"], function(margin,d3){return(
(g, y, title) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".title").data([title]).join("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", -margin.left)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(title))
)});
  main.variable(observer("margin")).define("margin", function(){return(
{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
)});
  main.variable(observer("height")).define("height", function(){return(
440
)});
  main.variable(observer("focusHeight")).define("focusHeight", function(){return(
100
)});
  main.variable(observer("d3")).define("d3", ["require"], function(require){return(
require("d3@6")
)});
  return main;
}
```

Comment: It appears this is a duplicate of https://talk.observablehq.com/t/understanding-observable-downloading-html-js/2906 but I would still like a working jsfiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is tricky, as the functions are observables and the viewof is returning a view of the brush (the min and max)

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7ry1dbh/)

```
/* new data */
var x = d3.timeDays(new Date(2015, 06, 01), new Date(2020, 10, 30));
var y = Array.from({length: x.length}, Math.random).map(n => Math.floor(n * 10) + 5);
var data = x.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    "date": v,
    "value": y[i]
  }
});

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
var height = 440;
var width = 600;
var focusHeight = 100;

var focusedArea = d3.extent(x);

  const svg = d3.select('#my_chart').append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .style("display", "block");

  const clipId = {id: "clip"};

  const clip = svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", clipId.id)
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right);

  const gx = svg.append("g");

  const gy = svg.append("g");

  const path = svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", `url(#${clipId.id})`)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue");

  const updateChart = (focusX, focusY) => {
      gx.call(xAxis, focusX, height);
      gy.call(yAxis, focusY, data.y);
      path.attr("d", area(focusX, focusY));
    };


/* begin observable code */
var focus = () => {
  const svg = d3.select("#focus").append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, focusHeight])
      .style("display", "block");
  const brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[margin.left, 0.5], [width - margin.right, focusHeight - margin.bottom + 0.5]])
      .on("brush", brushed)
      .on("end", brushended);

  const defaultSelection = [x(d3.utcYear.offset(x.domain()[1], -1)), x.range()[1]];

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis, x, focusHeight);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", area(x, y.copy().range([focusHeight - margin.bottom, 4])));

  const gb = svg.append("g")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, defaultSelection);

  function brushed({selection}) {
    if (selection) {
      svg.property("value", selection.map(x.invert, x).map(d3.utcDay.round));
      svg.dispatch("input");
        focusedArea = svg.property('value');
        update();
    }
  }

  function brushended({selection}) {
    if (!selection) {
      gb.call(brush.move, defaultSelection);
    }
  }
  return svg.node();
}

var update = function() {
  const [minX, maxX] = focusedArea;
  const maxY = d3.max(data, d => minX <= d.date && d.date <= maxX ? d.value : NaN);
  updateChart(x.copy().domain(focusedArea), y.copy().domain([0, maxY]));
}

var area = (x, y) => d3.area()
    .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(d => y(d.value))
    
var x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    
var xAxis = (g, x, height) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))
    
var yAxis = (g, y, title) => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".title").data([title]).join("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", -margin.left)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(title))
        



focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is per steps below - the output is in the snippet below and works equally as well in jsfiddle.

1. Small updates to `data` - see the comments, mainly use `value` not `close`
2. Bring in the Observable cell values outside of `focus` and `chart` first and include `width` - I've used the code in the `update` block later on in a function
3. Main change to `chart` is to remove the `return` section and handle the `chart` rendering in `chartUpdate` function which is called from the `brush` handler.
4. `focus` does not need to be a function returning `svg.node()` - this is perfectly valid but leaves the need to infer what it means. The brush start and end dates can be passed straight to the `chartUpdate` without needing to store the value in the `svg.property` and broadcast it with `dispatch` etc (although this is part of what the Observable is trying to demo)
5. `chartUdpate` is a simple lift of the `update` logic out of the `return` statement in `chart` where it accepts the scaling per the date range in the `brush`.

```js
// data
// Changes
// 1. use utcDays because scale is scaleUtc
// 2. rename x and y to xData and yData as x and y are scales
// 3. return 'value' not 'close'
// 4. add the y property for the axis label
const xData = d3.utcDays(new Date(2010, 06, 01), new Date(2020, 10, 30));
var yData = Array.from({length: xData.length}, Math.random).map(n => Math.floor(n * 10) + 5);
var data = xData.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    "date": v,
    "value": yData[i]
  }
});
Object.assign(data, {y: "↑ Close $"});

// lift from Observable - neither the focus or chart cells
// Changes
// 1. add width as Observable has it as a built-in
// 2. remove the update block
const height = 440;
const focusHeight = 100;
const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
// add width 
const width = 600;

const xAxis = (g, x, height) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));

const yAxis = (g, y, title) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".title").data([title]).join("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", -margin.left)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("fill", "currentColor")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(title));

const x = d3.scaleUtc()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
  
const area = (x, y) => d3.area()
  .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
  .x(d => x(d.date))
  .y0(y(0))
  .y1(d => y(d.value));
  
// Lift from chart block (first)
// Changes
// 1. need select, append not create
// 2. define a clipPath, discard the use of clipId
// 3. reference the clipPath in chartPth
// 4. rename some vars to specify they are for the chart
// 5. the logic in the return statement deferred to later
const svgChart = d3.select("#viz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .style("display", "block");
  
// replace clipId and use clippath 
svgChart.append("defs")
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", margin.left)
  .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
  .attr("height", height);
    
const chartGx = svgChart.append("g");
const chartGy = svgChart.append("g");

// refer to the clippath
const chartPath = svgChart.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue");
      
// lift from focus block (second)
// Changes
// 1. need select, append not create
// 2. change brushed function; don't use dispatch
// 3. svg.node() becomes svg.node().value (as in data 'value')
// 4. chartUpdate is new function with logic from chart cell
const svgFocus = d3.select("#viz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, focusHeight])
  .style("display", "block");

const brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([[margin.left, 0.5], [width - margin.right, focusHeight - margin.bottom + 0.5]])
  .on("brush", brushed)
  .on("end", brushended);
  
const defaultSelection = [x(d3.utcYear.offset(x.domain()[1], -1)), x.range()[1]];

svgFocus.append("g")
  .call(xAxis, x, focusHeight);

svgFocus.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("d", area(x, y.copy().range([focusHeight - margin.bottom, 4])));

const gb = svgFocus.append("g")
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, defaultSelection);

// update brushed to sync chart with focus
function brushed({selection}) {
  if (selection) {
    // update logic goes here - to get args for chartUpdate
    const [minX, maxX] = selection.map(x.invert, x).map(d3.utcDay.round);
    const maxY = d3.max(data, d => minX <= d.date && d.date <= maxX ? d.value : NaN);
    const focusX = x.copy().domain([minX, maxX]);
    const focusY = y.copy().domain([0, maxY]);
    
    // call chart update
    chartUpdate(focusX, focusY);
  } 
}

function brushended({selection}) {
  if (!selection) {
    gb.call(brush.move, defaultSelection);
  }
}

// chart  update
function chartUpdate(focusX, focusY) {
  chartGx.call(xAxis, focusX, height);
  chartGy.call(yAxis, focusY, data.y);
  chartPath.attr("d", area(focusX, focusY));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
```